# Is there a pretrained model that can detect and classify if a human is in a photo?

Tags: conv-neural-network, pre-trained-model, image-classification

I am trying to find a pre-trained model that will classify images based on if there is a human present in the photo or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the models trained on the `COCO` dataset for this.
For example, for Pytorch you can have a look at the official documentation concerning the provided models [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/models.html#object-detection-instance-segmentation-and-person-keypoint-detection).
There are more variety of models if you give it a simple search both for Pytorch and other frameworks.

You can check out the [COCO homepage](https://cocodataset.org/#home) if you need more information concerning the dataset and the tasks it supports.

You may also find These useful:

- [Detecting people using Yolo-OpenCV](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5270240/Using-Pretrained-Models-to-Detect-People-With-Open)
- [Yolo object detection in pytorch](https://gilberttanner.com/blog/yolo-object-detection-in-pytorch)
- [Another Yolo implementation in Pytorch](https://github.com/ayooshkathuria/pytorch-yolo-v3)
- [Similar question on ai.stackexchange](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/8668/are-there-any-pretrained-models-for-human-recognition-from-all-angles)

You can also utilize frameworks such as [Detectorn2](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2), [mmdetection](https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmdetection) for these tasks.(Or Tensorflow's [ObjectDetectionAPI](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) , ect)